# Jmeter server.bat file error

Tags: jmeter

Please give me solution for the below error.

> Could not find ApacheJmeter_core.jar ... ... Trying JMETER_HOME=.. Found ApacheJMeter_core.jar Created remote object: UnicastServerRef [liveRef: [endpoint:192.168.8.108:50019 ,objID:[-30cb105c:15ca098204b:-7fff, 5736149660821635846]]]

I tried the below way also, am not able to launch

"I just hard coded the path in my jmeter_server.bat."

Am doing testing now.. if any one knows please update here.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error at all, it means that you successfully launched a **JMeter slave** which is now waiting for a command from the **JMeter master**.

So now you need to start JMeter Master using one of the following approaches:

- Pass slave IP address via -R command-line argument like:

  ```
  jmeter -R 192.168.8.108 -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
  ```
- Define `remote_hosts` JMeter Property by adding the next line to *user.properties* file on JMeter Master node:

  ```
  remote_hosts=192.168.8.108
  ```

References:

- [JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

---

If you need just to open JMeter GUI you will need to launch **jmeter.bat** script or alternatively directly call java from JMeter's "bin" folder like:

```
java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar
```

Comment: Thanks your Reply Dmitri.